# How to check variable value through elif statement?

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to make a quick calculator and can't seem to get my Elif statements to read the variable value correctly. When run, the program just goes to the error statement. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
print("Enter a number:")

number1 = input()

print("Enter a second number:")

number2 = input()

operator = input("Enter a number to 1)Multiply 2)Divide 3)Add 4)Subtract :   ")

int(operator)

if operator == 1:
  result = number1 * number2
  print(result)
elif operator == 2:
  result = number1 / number2
  print(result)
elif operator == 3:
  result = number1 + number2
  print(result)
elif operator == 4:
  result = number1 - number2
  print(result)
else:
  print("Enter a correct number")
```

Comment: `operator = int(operator)`. As it is right now, you just throw away the result of the cast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not assigning the `int(operator)` to `operator` so change like this,

```
operator = int(operator)
```